# How do I empty logfiles in Ubuntu?

Tags: log

How do I empty logfiles in Ubuntu? I got message that root has less than 1 GB of space left.. I found out that logfile is huge, over 400 GB. (Does size of logfiles relate to root directory at all?)
I'm using Focal Fossa.

I'm unsure to use commands from older posts since I'm afraid they've been changed and I might empty something else in progress.

Comment: What is the "logfile" you mentioned? For routine maintenance see `man logrotate`.

Comment: I'm unsure what it exactly is, but most if(2,4 GB) it is under \var\log\lib\snapd\

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncomfortable with using the terminal then consider using a GUI package like `Stacer` downloadable from the ubuntu software center.

[image]

Running stacer and using the cleaning tool you can see graphically your Application Logs and  choose what to clear down by clicking on the check mark against each.

[image]

Comment: I tried Stacer and it showed kernel logs, ufw.log.1 and two syslogs as huge files. Are they safe to empty?

Comment: if they weren't safe to remove, Stacer wouldn't list them. I use Stacer often without drilling down on 20.04 (and 18.04 before that) and have never experienced a problem. If you remove a log, you won't have the reference later if you needed it, that's all.

Comment: @HetaRikala before deleting ANY log files, view them to determine why they are so large. Typically there's an error that repeats itself and fills the logs. This error needs to get fixed before manipulating any log files, as the problem will just return later.

Comment: @heynnema that said, (and I don't disagree) a shorter log file might just be easier to assimilate.

Comment: @24601 No forensic detective would ever consider getting rid of valuable data before looking at it first :-)

Comment: .. and they would first make a copy so as to preserve and protect but most end users eyes would just glaze over with the sheer weight of detail.

Comment: Well, here is the partial detail of one logfile(ufw.log) that has been slowly but surely hogging space all day.. (Can't paste whole log to pastebin since my computer temporarily freezes up when I try to do so.)
https://pastebin.com/rByDUqq3